# PHP Versions and exif_imagetype() Function

Tags: php, image, mime-types, fileinfo, image-extraction

Is `exif_imagetype()` function not supported by the `PHP Versions` greater than `5.0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php) it is still supported

Comment: there are some comments on configuration at the bottom of the page which may be relevant if you are on windows